# Running Java program from Batch script with correct number of arguments

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, arguments

I have a java program can take a variable amount of parameters. Something like:

```
package other;
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String arg: args) {/* do something */}
    }
}
```

I want to run this java program from a .bat script.

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp "/some.jar;other.jar" other.Main %1 %2 %3
```

With this I can call my .bat script like

```
> myscript.bat arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This works if I have 3 arguments, but there can be a variable amount of arguments passed. How can I pass them all to the java program?

Comment: I think you can pass arguments with %*: "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp "/some.jar;other.jar" other.Main %*

Comment: You are correct. Simple enough. Add it as an answer, I'll accept. Maybe with explanation for others.

Comment: `%*` expands to all parameters, I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%*` holds all arguments passed to a script.